# Query about feature extraction and classification of EEG signal in MATLAB using wavelet transform and SVM,NN

Tags: matlab

I am doing a project on EEG. For this purpose

1. I have an excel file having around 10000 values in only 1 column..I want to convert this file into a matrix of order 512*14..I am doing it manually which is taking much time..can anyone tell me how to do this by applying window,especially hamming window or any other easy method please..?
2. I have extracted features like power and entropy using wavelet transform but the differentiation in results is not seen..can anyone tell the program or tell whether this code is correct or not..
3. Also anybody knows how to use SVM and NN classifier for EEG classification? Please tell as soon as possible..as I am urgently in need of it..

   tic

   clear all

   close all

   clc

subject 1 - sad..............................

a11 = xlsread('7168sub1-sad.xlsx');

[mat11] = vec2mat(a11,14)

size(mat11)

t11 = wpdec(a11,5,'db2');

cfs1s1 = wpcoef(t11,[1 0]);%..decompose into higher n lower freq...

cfs2s1 = wpcoef(t11,[1 1]);%..discard..

cfs3s1 = wpcoef(t11,[2 0]);%..decompose..

cfs4s1 = wpcoef(t11,[2 1]);%..gamma...

cfs5s1 = wpcoef(t11,[3 0]);%..decompose..

cfs6s1 = wpcoef(t11,[3 1]);%..beta..

cfs7s1 = wpcoef(t11,[4 0]);%..decompose..

cfs8s1 = wpcoef(t11,[4 1]);%..alpha..

cfs9s1 = wpcoef(t11,[5 0]);%..delta..

cfs10s1 = wpcoef(t11,[5 1]);%..theta..

fprintf('ENTROPIES of DELTA,THETA,ALPHA,BETA,GAMMA ARE :\n')

fprintf('SUBJECT 1 - SAD and ANGRY EMOTIONS :\n')

E11d = wentropy(cfs9s1,'shannon')

E11t = wentropy(cfs10s1,'shannon')

E11a = wentropy(cfs8s1,'shannon')

E11b = wentropy(cfs6s1,'shannon')

E11g = wentropy(cfs4s1,'shannon')

%.................subject 1 - angry.......................

a21 = xlsread('7168sub1-angry.xlsx')

[mat21] = vec2mat(a21,14)

size(mat21)

t21 = wpdec(a21,5,'db2');

cfs1a1 = wpcoef(t21,[1 0]);

cfs2a1 = wpcoef(t21,[1 1]);

cfs3a1 = wpcoef(t21,[2 0]);

cfs4a1 = wpcoef(t21,[2 1]);

cfs5a1 = wpcoef(t21,[3 0]);

cfs6a1 = wpcoef(t21,[3 1]);

cfs7a1 = wpcoef(t21,[4 0]);

cfs8a1 = wpcoef(t21,[4 1]);

cfs9a1 = wpcoef(t21,[5 0]);

cfs10a1 = wpcoef(t21,[5 1]);

%............Find entropy :...................

E21d = wentropy(cfs9a1,'shannon')

E21t = wentropy(cfs10a1,'shannon')

E21a = wentropy(cfs8a1,'shannon')

E21b = wentropy(cfs6a1,'shannon')

E21g = wentropy(cfs4a1,'shannon')

%...............Plot ENTROPIES...............

x = 1:1:5;
figure(1)

%================= all sad ========================

%------------------ sub-1 -------------------------

plot(1, E11d, 'b*')

hold on

plot(1, E11t, 'b*')

hold on

plot(1, E11a, 'b*')

hold on

plot(1, E11b, 'b*')

hold on

plot(1, E11g, 'b*')

hold on

%================= all angry ========================

%------------------ sub-1 -------------------------

plot(1, E21d, 'r*')

hold on

plot(1, E21t, 'r*')

hold on

plot(1, E21a, 'r*')

hold on

plot(1, E21b, 'r*')

hold on

plot(1, E21g, 'r*')

hold on

%========================================================

toc

this program is shown for 1 person,in same way i have done for 10 persons.please tell me is it correct??

Answer (score 0):

I also work on EEG analysis using Wavelet transformation and SVM Classifier.Use 1-D or 2-D wavelet transformation in MATLAB general view. MAny research Paper give 256 Hz Sampling frequency. wavelet transformation use for decompose signal in particular band, i attach one image. feature extract before decomposition of signal, after decomposition, and after Reconstruction the signal. In MATLAB, wavedec and wavedec2 respectively used for 1-D and 2-D wavelet transformation. after decomposition extract co efficient detail and approximatw using detcoef and appcoef function according to level. then reconstruction using waverec function.

thanks